# Tensorflow text parsing

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I am trying to parse text with Tensorflow. Lets say I have CSV file that looks like this:

```
foo,bar
```

And I want the output to be an array of the values:

```
[foo,bar]
```

How would you do it? I was thinking about creating some kind of hash for each word (value) for the input, but I have no idea what to do for the output.

I am not parsing CSV files, I only used them as an example.

Comment: How is this parsing related to TensorFlow? You can do it with a few lines of pure Python, right?

Comment: Yes but I wanted to know how to do it using the neural network.

Comment: That does not make much sense... the neural network processes a vector of numbers and for each concrete problem you'd need to design some input and output transformation. You could of course put an identity neural network between such transformations and use that as starting point for further experiments.

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, lines = reader.read(...)

# if your data is ccv
list-of-tensors = tf.decode_csv(lines, ...)

# if your data is just a line of text
a-sparse-tensor = tf.string_split(lines, ...)
```